# Получение каналов YCbCr изображения

Tags: python, изображения, jpeg

Во многих статях про JPEG говориться, что для кодирований картинка из RGB переводится в YCbCr. В пример обычно приводят картинку пейзажа[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Если с каналом яркости всё понятно, то с цветоразностными непонятно как получить их изображение. Хотелось бы получить простой способ(в иделале на Python) получать по картинке все три YCbCr канала, и чтобы цветоразностные отображались цветом.

Comment: Ну формулы то известны. А в каком-нибудь PIL или cv2 наверняка даже функции готовые есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вам подсказали в комментарии для этого подойдет PIL. В данной библиотеке есть способ конвертации из RGB в YCbCr. Для отображения подойдет matplotlib, но для каждого канала придется задать подходящий colormap.

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = Image.open("image.jpeg")
ycbcr = im.convert('YCbCr')

print(ycbcr.getbands())

(y, cb, cr) = ycbcr.split()

plt.figure()
plt.title("Original")
plt.imshow(im)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(131)
plt.title("Y")
plt.imshow(y, cmap="gray")
plt.subplot(132)
plt.title("Cb")
plt.imshow(cb, cmap="Blues")
plt.subplot(133)
plt.title("Cr")
plt.imshow(cr, cmap="Reds")
plt.show()
```